# viewForHeaderInSection is called for every section but the first UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a `UITableView` and a `UITableViewController` which is the delegate of the table view. I have multiple sections in my `UITableView`, and I need to set a custom header for the first section. Unfortunately, the method `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView!` (swift) is being called for every section but section 0 which is the first section. All of my other `UITableView` delegate and datasource methods are working correctly and I have no methods that should override this method.

Comment: You are going to have to show more code because something strange is obviously going on.

Comment: Which code would you like to see?

Comment: Ideally the smallest possible amount of code that you can create that still shows the problem. Strip out all the unnecessary code from your UITableViewController and then post the whole controller. Who knows, you will probably find the problem yourself by going through that process. As you delete code, you will probably find the piece of code causing the problem.

Answer (score 10):

From the documentation:

> This method only works correctly when
>   tableView:heightForHeaderInSection: is also implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and, although I expect this isn't an universally working solution, for me the cause was that I returned 0 height for the headers in the first place. So, please make sure what you return on your `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` method.